# Is "I'm afraid to the death of.." used to emphasize when I'm in fear of something?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

It's taken from the other site. The context is, there's a provided question and someone will be asked to answer it and the answer will open to be corrected.

The question:

> Lots of people are scared of heights. What about you? Do you have or
> have you ever had any fears?

Someone's answer (Let's say he's A):

> Yes, I have afraid to the death but I'm learning to normalize more
> because is a natural cicle of life.

The other person who is an English native speaker has corrected him (Let's say he's B):

> Yes, I am afraid to the death of it, but I'm learning to normalise it
> more because is a natural circle of life.

I'm questioning about B's correction, whether the phrase **I am afraid to the death of it** is equivalent to

1. **I am *absolutely* afraid of it**. *or*
2. **I am afraid of death**. (Please correct me if it needs "the" before death).

I'm sure that the appropriate preposition after **afraid** is **of**, because I've made it sure in my dictionary (OALD). If I misunderstood, could you tell me the grammatical sentence that A should write?

Comment: We can say 'I'm scared to death' meaning 'I am so afraid I might die of fear'. It is an exaggeration for emphasis, like 'I am bored to tears'. No dying or weeping is really envisaged. 'Afraid to the death' of' something is odd and possibly archaic. Only 'scared' works here. It has nothing to do with being afraid **of** death.

Comment: My guess would be that A meant 'I'm afraid of death' and 'it's part of the natural _cycle_ of life'.